# Loop only iterates first instance and how do I extract single filenames via os.walk?

Tags: search, for-loop, file-io, os.walk

Objective: A script that searches a directory for axograph files and performs as series of computations and returns either the values or saves it to CSV file.

> Update: Data comes from Axographio raw files of intracellular recordings where each file has 4 waves of data. I seek to do the very basic ehpys calculations of properties: 
>   input resistance, 
>   half-width at half-maximum, 
>   rheobase, SAG potential, 
>   membrane time constant
>   afterhyperpolarisation.
>
> I found python module "stimfit" which has useful libraries for this but it does not import properly. I´m currently troubleshooting this package.
>
> This is my first script and first recordings, so if anyone has ideas, please share.

Problem 1. "f = axographio.read(filename)" only takes one argument with a string specific to "filename.axgd". I cant put this method alone since the resulting "file" is a list object and not the single instance of each filenames that I seek. I think that above function can work with "f=axographio.read(file)" if I can get that file object as a list or array of the filenames and extract them.

> Problem 1 is now solved with `f = axographio.read(os.path.join(root, file))` - it was unclear that os.path worked within the axographio module.

Problem 2. I can print all my files as list of strings but unable to extract and open each single file (even with file=open(blablabla.).

> Update: I can either loop for each open file or save them to a list or array. I dont mind advice on best practice on this. axograph seems to work well with NumPy array but list is tempting since it has more flexibility. Any advice on this?

Note: its´s not necessary to make this complicated. The key point is to perform computations on multiple files at my choosing. Whether I save this into file or have more or less control is a matter of taste and time.

```
 -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

@author: Martenzi
"""
import os,sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import axographio
from scipy import stats
import re
import os
from collections import defaultdict


""" Search a directory for all Axograph files """
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".axgd"):
            f = axographio.read(os.path.join(root, file))

                plt.show(file)
                plt.plot(f.data[0],f.data[1])
                plt.plot(f.data[0],f.data[2])
                plt.plot(f.data[0],f.data[3])
                plt.plot(f.data[0],f.data[4])
```

""" Below is various code snippets that I have tried out. They are not in specific order. I have tried things and stacked it as comments """

```
#            if(line == 'foo'):
#                line = next(irofile)  #BEWARE, This could raise StopIteration!
#                print line
#            for i in file:            
#                cells = [];
#                cells.append(file);
#            for index, w in enumerate (loopme):
#            cells = array ( [i] ,dtype=complex)
#            print(file)
#            for k in file:
#                d = defaultdict(int)
#                d[k].append()
#            m=self.fileFormatRegex.match(file)
#            self.processFile(root, open(os.path.join(r"/", root, file)), age, inString)

#            infile = open(cells,"r")
#            fullpath = os.path.walk(files)
#            infile = open(file, "r")
#            f = open(file ["r"][buffering])
#            with open(infile, mode='r'):
##                f = axographio.read(file)
#                print(file)

#                f = axographio.read(cell)
#                with open(fullpath, 'r') as f:

#                f = axographio.read(file)
#                data = re.sub(r'(\s*function\s+.*\s*{\s*)',
#                    r'\1echo "The function starts here."',
#                    f.read())
#            with open(fullpath, 'w') as f:
#                f.write(data)
```